# SharePoint list search for choice columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, search, column, choice-field

I am having an issue with searching a list based on the contents of a choice column. I seem to be able to search by text-based fields, but I have an important field called Category that is a choice column with options like "Tables, Chairs, Sofas..". When I type "Tables" in to the list search bar nothing appears. Can we not search based on the contents of choice columns? I know that we are able to filter and from my perspective that is the better option, but our client would like to be able to do all of their searching from the single search bar. I have not been able to find anything that addresses this specific scenario.